# Python Fill in the missing value based on the same date available in previous years

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, python-datetime, imputation

I have a `df` with `DateTimeIndex` (hourly readings) and 3 years of temperature data.

```
Time                   Temp 
1/2/2017 13:00          31     
1/2/2017 14:00           NA     
1/2/2017 15:00           22
```

Now, I want to replace the missing Temperature readings as follows: if my data from 1st February 2017 at 2 pm is missing, I would like to fill these missing values with data from 2 pm on 1st Feb 2016 and 1st Feb 2018 (averaging them). Note that temperature data depends largely on the time of the day (obviously) so I think this would be the best approach.

I have tried interpolate and ffill methods. Interpolate massively underestimated the readings and ffill doesn't work well because I have long periods of missing values.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
print(df.fillna(df['Temp'].mean()))
```

Or use:

```
print(df.ffill()['Temp'].add(df.bfill()['Temp']).div(2))
```

Both Output:

```
             Time  Temp
0  1/2/2017 13:00  31.0
1  1/2/2017 14:00  26.5
2  1/2/2017 15:00  22.0
```

Comment: The first one is quick and handy :-) +1

Comment: The first method is not great for this purpose. Because average temperature during the day is a lot higher than during the evening for the geographical location.

Comment: @SakibShahriar Yah i know

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pandas.DataFrame.interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with `inplace=True` .

This can provide you different methos like which you may use at your ease:

`method : {‘linear’, ‘time’, ‘index’, ‘values’, ‘nearest’, ‘zero’,‘slinear’, ‘quadratic’, ‘cubic’, ‘barycentric’, ‘krogh’, ‘polynomial’, ‘spline’ ‘piecewise_polynomial’, ‘pchip’}`

```
>>> df['Temp'].interpolate(inplace=True)
>>> df
             Time  Temp
0  1/2/2017 13:00  31.0
1  1/2/2017 14:00  26.5
2  1/2/2017 15:00  22.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but is linear interpolation a good idea for this? Because temperature values range from 40 degrees at day time to around 20 degrees during evening

Comment: `interpolate` gives you the flexibility to fill the missing values with different kinds of interpolations between the values like linear (which fillna does not provide) , please see the doc if that helps or you can  give it try to see how it works with your data.